# egrep in bash script not working

Tags: bash, grep, alias, command-substitution, amazon-s3

I have this set of commands :

```
s3ls="aws s3 ls $ssyss3/ --recursive --human-readable --summarize"
egrepCommand="egrep '$currentDate|Total'"
totalSize=$(echo $s3ls|$egrepCommand| awk -F 'Total Size:' '{print $2}'|sed '/^$/d')
echo $totalSize
```

but I'm getting this error :

```
egrep '2019-05-11|Total': command not found
```

What am I missing?

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 7):

As it says on the tin. You create a command name which is `egrep '2019-05-11|Total'` and then try to call it. This is not a `egrep` followed by a parameter but a complete command name. What you want is more likely:

```
totalSize=$(echo $s3ls| egrep "$currentDate|Total" | awk -F 'Total Size:' '{print $2}'|sed '/^$/d')
```

If necessary you can use a variable to hold the parameter:

```
egrepParm="$currentDate|Total" 
totalSize=$(echo $s3ls| egrep "$egrepParm" | awk -F 'Total Size:' '{print $2}'|sed '/^$/d')
```

Some will say that in a script it is best to use `grep -E` instead of `egrep`

PS: An aliased command will work in the command prompt/terminal but not in a script, so trying the command in the terminal isn't proof that it will work in a script. In bash, use `type {commandname}` to check if the name is a real command or an alias. `egrep` can be implemented as an alias in some Unix versions, in my Ubuntu it is a plain command.

Comment: You can store the command, but you must use an array: `cmd=( grep -E "$currentDate|Total" )` then `echo "$s3ls" | "${cmd[@]}" | ...`